# Sorting an 2d array in alphabetical order

Tags: java

I am sorting a 2D array and am having a few issues. When i sort it starts to work for the first couple and doesn't finish. Here is my code then I will post my output.The first part of sectionArray[] contains 2 sections. In the second part of sectionArray[][] contains different student objects. I need to sort these object's String names alphabetically for each section.

```
public void sortByName(){
    String temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for (int a = 0; a < sectionArray[i].length-1; a++){
            if (sectionArray[i][a].getName().compareToIgnoreCase(sectionArray[i][a+1].getName()) > 0){
                temp = sectionArray[i][a].getName();
                sectionArray[i][a].setName(sectionArray[i][a+1].getName());
                sectionArray[i][a+1].setName(temp);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Progress Report

Section 1

Johnson 90.6  A

Aniston 81.2  B

Cooper_ 82.2  B

Gupta__ 72.2  C

Blair__ 52.2  F

 Section 2

Clark__ 59.2  F

Kennedy 63.4  D

Bronson 90.0  A

Sunny__ 84.8  B

Smith__ 75.4  C

Diana__ 68.8  D

AFTER SORTING THE 2D ARRAY

Progress Report

Section 1

Aniston 90.6  A

Cooper_ 81.2  B

Gupta__ 82.2  B

Blair__ 72.2  C

Johnson 52.2  F

 Section 2

Clark__ 59.2  F

Bronson 63.4  D

Kennedy 90.0  A

Smith__ 84.8  B

Diana__ 75.4  C

Sunny__ 68.8  D
```

Comment: posting the input would be helpful

Comment: there is a mistake in your second `for` cycle, you are not taking into account last element of array. and your bubble sorting is wrong. you are doing only one iteration over array, algorithm requires redoing this until there are no changes to array -> array is sorted. Better use built-in merge sort as recommended in answer.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could just use a comparator :

```
Arrays.sort(myList, new Comparator<Student>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
        return s1.getName().compareTo(s2);
    }

});
```

Comment: Hint: You need to use this instead of your second `for` cycle

Comment: @jend I have tried using the Arrays.sort method and it will not work because i am accessing a object's string.For example when I  do this "Arrays.sort(sectionArray[0]);" I get this error    "java.lang.ClassCastException: Student cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable"

Comment: Either make Student implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)  interface or pass a comparator as a second argument to Arrays.sort(...) like I posted.

Comment: You can covert out your `String` to `char[]`